CSS Grid - make next row take 100% width and space items evenly
I have a list of items in a row. I want each item to take up a minimum width. When the user resizes the screen I want the items to overflow to the next line.


.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="container">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
  <div>Eight</div>
  <div>Nine</div>
  <div>Ten</div>
</div>



What I want is for the last row to always take up 100% of the width. Is this doable with CSS Grid?
Ex: If Nine and Ten are overflowing I want the items to span from end to end and be centered.
One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight 
          Nine         Ten

or in a tighter space
One Two Three Four 
Five Six Seven Eight 
    Nine   Ten


Not possible AFAIK with CSS-Grid. CSS can't detect overflow and so elements can't be selected because they have overflowed.

Why grid? This is classic flexbox apply display: flex to container and flex: 1 to children

https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jOjWJdY

CSS grid (read the property out loud) is not the right tool for automating the children's grow.
CSS flex and flex-grow (on the child elements) is — while using CSS wrap


.container {
  display: flex; /* Don't use "grid" when "flex" is what you need */
  flex-wrap: wrap;   /* Or: flex-flow: row wrap; // children to new line if they overflow */
  
  & div {
    flex: 1; /* shorthand for: flex-grow:1; flex-shrink:1; flex-basis:0; */
    outline: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em 2em;
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
  <div>Eight</div>
  <div>Nine</div>
  <div>Ten</div>
</div>



